# Testing http connections

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am making a spring boot application where I am looking to enable retries on certain http connections. I am a little confused on how this application is to compare the status code and trigger the function for the retry to execute. Any insight on this would be helpful, I am under assumption there is a function that retrieves status codes but I am unable to find it. Below is my the class I have created:

public class HttpFailedConnectionRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {

```
@Value("SomeValue")
private Integer maxAttempts;

public HttpFailedConnectionRetryPolicy() {
    final NeverRetryPolicy doNotRetry = new NeverRetryPolicy();
    final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);

    this.setExceptionClassifier(new Classifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy>() {
        @Override
        public RetryPolicy classify(Throwable classifiable) {
            if (condition) {
                return simpleRetryPolicy;
            }
            return new NeverRetryPolicy();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If your exception is of type HttpStatusCodeException, you can check e.getStatusCode()

your condition should be

```
public RetryPolicy classify(Throwable classifiable) {
        if (classifiable instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
            if(((HttpStatusCodeException)classifiable).getStatusCode().value!=404)
            return simpleRetryPolicy;
        }
        return new NeverRetryPolicy();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I am looking to set retries on all failed connection except 404. Can you explain a little more what e.getStatusCode() does? I had looked at that before but was unable to find a good explanation.